# How to change eGit configuration location?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, egit

I have copied a workspace used by Eclipse (Mars) to a new directory (using tar to ensure permissions/ownership is intact). Everything is working well except that eGit is pointing to the old .gitconfig files in the original workspace.  For example:

```
/workspace1 (original workspace)
/workspace2 (new copy)
```

...and when using "workspace2" I go to the "Git Repositories" view, right click a repository and select "Properties", and the "Configuration" "location" is pointing to "workspace1" and changing branches will change "workspace1". The location path is something like "/Users/alex/workspaces/workspace1/project1/.git/config" and I just need to change "workspace1" to "workspace2".

All I need to do is change the path but I can't find this text in any configuration file (using grep) and this value is read-only in the dialog. Does anyone know how I can change the path? It seems much easier to do this than disconnecting/reconnecting, etc.

Many thanks in advance!
Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config of **Git Reposititories** view are stored in "/Users/alex/workspaces/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.egit.core.prefs". However, I think it's NOT a good idea to edit it directly.

I suggest you change the path using EGit function:

1. Select project and right click: `Team -> Disconnect`
2. In **Git Reposititories** view, Select repository and right click: `Remove Reposititory from View`
3. Select project and right click: `Team -> Share Project...`
4. Select **GIT** as reposititory type and apply default.

Comment: Thanks beckyang!  I appreciate the warning that editing the configuration file is not advised, but the good news is that after changing it, it seems to be working perfectly. My initial test involved make and committing changes to git in the original workspace, which I was able to synchronize in the new workspace.  So far so good.  Again - many thanks!